# Using Microsoft Fakes to Mock

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, microsoft-fakes

I have sealed classes with async(.net 4.5) methods that need to be mocked.  I'm using Microsoft Fakes and so they will be "shims".  The following code is an example of what I need to do.  It builds but when run and the "LoginAsync" method within the "Login" controller method is called, the test hangs.

```
  [TestMethod]
  public async Task LoginPost_Returns() {

     using (ShimsContext.Create()) {
        var c = new TestController();
        var user=new User();

        Fakes.ShimUserManager.AllInstances.LoginAsyncString = (um, u) => new Task<IUser>(() => { return user; });

        //call controller method  
        var result = await c.Login(model, returnUrl) as ViewResult;
        var expectedViewName = "Index";
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedViewName, result.ViewName);
     }

//Controller method
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
     var user = await UserManager.LoginAsync(model.UserName, model.password);
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the `Task` constructor in `async` code. If you just need a completed `Task` with a return value, use `Task.FromResult`:

```
IUser user = new User();
Fakes.ShimUserManager.AllInstances.LoginAsyncString = (um, u) => Task.FromResult(user);
```

As an additional tip, it's a good idea to cover these cases in your unit tests:

- Synchronous success (`Task.FromResult(user)`).
- Asynchronous success (`Task.Run(() => user)`).
- Asynchronous error (`Task.Run(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException("or whatever"); return user; })`).

Comment: In the error case, wouldn't explicitly specifying the delegate type be clearer than having unreachable `return`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Fakes.ShimUserManager.AllInstances.LoginAsyncString =
    (um, u) => new Task<IUser>(() => { return user; });
```

This creates an unstarted `Task`. Your code hangs, because the `Task` is never started. To fix that, you can:

1. Use `Task.Run()` (or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`), which returns an already started `Task`.
2. Use `Task.FromResult()`. which returns an already completed `Task`.
3. Make the lambda `async`:

   ```
   Fakes.ShimUserManager.AllInstances.LoginAsyncString = async (um, u) => user;
   ```

Comment: Good point about the task never starting.  I was thinking something along those lines.  To your second point the LoginAsync method(returns IUser) is a business layer method and the Login method(returns ViewResult) is a controller action method.  They are not the same method.

Comment: @user2507103 I think I understand now. I have removed the part about the types from my answer.

Comment: I like the option of making lamdba async. One must then include an await as well - which could just be a delay of say 1 ms and then go on to return what you want to return. Making lambda async mimics the target method which is being shimmed more closely and will be easier for anyone else to understand as well.